# D3.js line chart grid issue

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

i have created a line chart using d3.js and added x and y grid in the chart. Only y-axis grid lines are coming and not x-axis grid lines.

I want to create grid like shown in the image below and a line at the top of y-axis, so it will look like perfect rectangle.

[image]

```js
var data = [{
  x: '1-May-12',
  y: 5
}, {
  x: '30-Apr-12',
  y: 28
}, {
  x: '27-Apr-12',
  y: 58
}, {
  x: '26-Apr-12',
  y: 88
}, {
  x: '25-Apr-12',
  y: 8
}, {
  x: '24-Apr-12',
  y: 48
}, {
  x: '23-Apr-12',
  y: 28
}, {
  x: '20-Apr-12',
  y: 68
}, {
  x: '19-Apr-12',
  y: 8
}, {
  x: '18-Apr-12',
  y: 58
}, {
  x: '17-Apr-12',
  y: 5
}, {
  x: '16-Apr-12',
  y: 80
}, {
  x: '13-Apr-12',
  y: 38
}];

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 35,
    left: 50
  },

  width = 1200 - (margin.left + margin.right);
height = 360 - 2 * (margin.top + margin.bottom);

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(0).tickSize(0)
  .tickFormat("").outerTickSize(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
  .orient("left").tickSize(0).ticks(0)
  .tickFormat("");

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr("class", "bg-color")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function make_x_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  );

// Draw the y Grid lines
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  );

xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return parseDate(d.x);
}));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.y;
})]);


data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseDate(a.x) - parseDate(b.x);
});

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

// Define the line
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(parseDate(d.x));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  });

svg.append('path')
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .attr('d', lineGen(data));
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See another example on jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/cmqzh33x/

```js
var data = [{
  x: '1-May-12',
  y: 5
}, {
  x: '30-Apr-12',
  y: 28
}, {
  x: '27-Apr-12',
  y: 58
}, {
  x: '26-Apr-12',
  y: 88
}, {
  x: '25-Apr-12',
  y: 8
}, {
  x: '24-Apr-12',
  y: 48
}, {
  x: '23-Apr-12',
  y: 28
}, {
  x: '20-Apr-12',
  y: 68
}, {
  x: '19-Apr-12',
  y: 8
}, {
  x: '18-Apr-12',
  y: 58
}, {
  x: '17-Apr-12',
  y: 5
}, {
  x: '16-Apr-12',
  y: 80
}, {
  x: '13-Apr-12',
  y: 38
}];

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 35,
    left: 50
  },

  width = 1200 - (margin.left + margin.right);
height = 360 - 2 * (margin.top + margin.bottom);

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y");
var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return parseDate.parse(d.x);
}));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.y;
})]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom").ticks(0).tickSize(0)
  .tickFormat("").outerTickSize(0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
  .orient("left").tickSize(0).ticks(0)
  .tickFormat("");

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr("class", "bg-color")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function make_x_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(25)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(25);
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  );

// Draw the y Grid lines
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat("")
  );


data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseDate.parse(a.x) - parseDate.parse(b.x);
});

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

// Define the line
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(parseDate.parse(d.x));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  });

svg.append('path')
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .attr('d', lineGen(data));
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The height was off.  Should have been     .tickSize(height, 0, 0).  In the process of debugging it, I moved the scale definition up and changed the parsing of the date function to trace it a little better.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis Thank You for the solution but it is incomplete. Please take a look at the picture attached with this question. I wish to have grid lines between the ticks lines and there are excess lines coming out at top of the graph. Please can you tell me how to remove them, so it will look like a rectangular. I am trying to create a graph exactly like the graph shown in the pic.

Comment: @nikunj2512 Just change the ticks(5) to something larger ticks(25) in my edited example.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis by changing the ticks(5) to ticks(25) will only increase the number of ticks but how to make lines between the ticks like drawn in the picture above. For example on Y-axis, the ticks start from 0 and next tick after 0 is 100 but there is one more tick between 0 and 100 without the tick value. How to get that kind of behavior? Also by increasing the number of ticks will not remove the extra extended ticks which are visible in your answer. How to remove those extra lines?

Comment: @nikunj2512 The vertical lines are now showing.  What in particular is different?  Can you be a little more explicit?  Your grid and your axis ticks are independently defined.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis if you observe the bottom right side of the both axis from where the axis starts you will not find any of the ticks crossing into negative x and y axis. They meet perfectly at (0,0).   I was hoping to have same at the top of the graph where ticks of x and y axis meet. Or just imagine a rectangular box and inside the box we drawn vertical and horizontal lines but these lines are not crossing the rectangle boundaries. I wish to have both axis and ticks to be drawn like this.

Comment: @nikunj2512 Do .nice() on the scales to get the extents to a 'nice' domain.  If you want a solid rect around it, you can always add a 'rect' too.  If you want the ticks to show every other, give it a ticksize (and a tick count for that matter).  https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/cmqzh33x/

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis Thank You for the solution.